# Not able to launch ngrok in a separate process in Python 2

Tags: python, shell, ngrok

Up until a couple of months ago, this command used to work just fine. Now it doesn't. What's wrong?

```
bashCommand = "nohup /Users/myname/ngrok http 8889 </dev/null >/dev/null 2>&1 &"
process = subprocess.Popen(bashCommand.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output, error = process.communicate()
```

It results in the following error-

```
ERROR:  You must specify a single argument: a port or address to tunnel to.
ERROR:  You specified 5 arguments: [8889 </dev/null >/dev/null 2>&1 &]
ERROR:  For example, to expose port 80, run 'ngrok http 80'.
```

Comment: Does that work in console?

Comment: Yes, the same command works on console.